# changing color of a cell in table using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table created with javascript. I would like to change color of a cell to red, when you click on it. I know i should propably use onClick event. But I am not sure how to use it in this specific task.

```js
var width = parseInt(prompt("Put width", "here"));
var height = parseInt(prompt("Put height", "here"));

function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("chessboard");
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      row.insertCell(j);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#chessboard {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: black
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div>
    <table id="chessboard"></table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Put a click listener on the table. When it gets called, look at the *event.target* to get the element that was clicked on (it will be a cell as there are no other elements in the cell). Set the cell's *style.backgroundColor* property to the appropriate value (e.g. 'red').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `click` event to all cells.

First, you'll need to store the original color somewhere so that you can change it back to normal when clicked again.

To do that, you could make use of `data-*` attribute. Now, to assign the correct `white` and `black` colors to corresponding cells' `data-color` attributes, you could use this JavaScript equivalent,

```
row.children[j].setAttribute('data-color', ((i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 != 0)) ? 'black' : 'white')
```

for this part of CSS,

```
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: black
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black
}
```

Now, since the original colors are stored, you could simply extract the corresponding colors stored in the `data-color` attribute and change it back to normal if its `backgroundColor` is `red`.

---

```js
var width = parseInt(prompt("Put width", "here"));
var height = parseInt(prompt("Put height", "here"));

function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("chessboard");
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      row.insertCell(j);
      row.children[j].setAttribute('data-color', ((i % 2 != 0 && j % 2 == 0) || (i % 2 == 0 && j % 2 != 0)) ? 'black' : 'white')
      row.children[j].addEventListener('click', function() {
        this.style.backgroundColor = (this.style.backgroundColor == 'red') ? this.getAttribute('data-color') : this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      });
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#chessboard {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: black
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div>
    <table id="chessboard"></table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: yes, this is how i imagine it, but i forgot to ask, how could i change color back to normal, if i click it again?

Comment: i think in didn't ask that correctly. First version was ok, what i was trying to ask is, when i click on cell it turns red, when i click on other cell it turns also red. But when i click on red cell it goes back to normal

Comment: @MihaLavrič - Updated the answer again. :) I hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can add an onclick listener to each cell which add a `selected` class to it. You also just need to track what was selected previously so you can remove the `selected` class from it:

```js
var width = parseInt(prompt("Put width", "here"));
var height = parseInt(prompt("Put height", "here"));

// tracks the selected cell
var selectedCell = null;

// handles the clicks
function selectCell() {
  // remove from previous if there is one
  if (selectedCell != null) {
    selectedCell.classList.remove('selected');
  }

  // mark cell as selected
  selectedCell = this;
  this.classList.add('selected');
}

function myFunction() {
  var table = document.getElementById("chessboard");
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    var row = table.insertRow(i);
    for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
      var cell = row.insertCell(j);
      // bind the selectCell function to this cell
      cell.onclick = selectCell.bind(cell);
    }
  };
}
```

```css
#chessboard {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse
}
td {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
  background: black;
}
tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
  background: black;
}
td.selected {
  background: red !important;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div>
    <table id="chessboard"></table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Or the selected cell can be found using `document.querySelector('.selected')`. ;-) How well supported is [*classList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#Browser_compatibility)?

Comment: It avoids the global *selectedCell*, a closure could be used instead.